# Selecting a single element from an array, within an "if" statement

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement, include

Creating a method that receives input from a user -- and if said input includes any word from a predetermined array, it prints the word "success!" Otherwise, if the input doesn't include a word from that array, it prints the word "failure."

My ideal would be to create a scenario where I can populate the array with as many elements as I want, and the method will always reference that array when deciding how to react to the user's input.

When I run it, however, I get an error message saying "no implicit conversion of Array into String."

My code is below. Appreciate any and all help! Thanks.

```
            def hello
            word_bank = ["hello", "hi", "howdy"]
            print "Say a word: "
            greeting = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_s

            if greeting.include?(word_bank[0..2])
               puts "success!"
              else
                puts "failure."
              end

            end

            hello
```

Answer (score 3):

`include?` is an array's method.

```
word_bank = ["hello", "hi", "howdy"]
print "Say a word: "
greeting = gets.chomp

if word_bank.include?(greeting)
  puts "success!"
else
  puts "failure."
end

puts [1,2,3].include?(1) # true
puts [1,2,3].include?(4) # false
```

If `word_bank` was big, for performance reason we should use a set instead of an array.

```
require 'set'

word_bank = Set.new(["hello", "hi", "howdy"])
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Ursus. This makes perfect sense. Knew I was close -- really appreciate the help!

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Comment: If `word_bank` is large, consider converting it to a set: `require 'set'; `word_bank_set = `word_bank.to_set`. Then `if word_bank_set.include?(greeting)`, which is a very fast lookup, as sets are hashes under the covers.

Comment: Cary I updated my answer even I think this is not the case. It looks like a school exercise.

Comment: Thanks Cary and Ursus. You could definitely call it a school exercise -- thought I'm actually just trying to teach myself on off-hours from my day job :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd solve the issue, I haven't tested it though but it should work.

```
def hello
  word_bank = ['hello', 'hi', 'howdy']
  print 'Say a word: '
  greeting = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_s

    word_bank.each do |w|

    w == greeting ? (puts 'success') : (puts 'failure')

  end   
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help @bork -- will try this out and let you know how it tests.